# C# linq to sql group multiple rows

Tags: c#, sql, linq

**Update:**

There is one more table called Location special signs. It pairs stored location ID and special signs. It is necessary to make the result in variable **SpecialSignsLocation** and get the following:

```
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> SpecialSignsLocation = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

   //json result
    ...
        SpecialSigns:  {
                    BodyType:  [1, 2],
                    Hair:  [3, 1, 2],
                    SpecialSignsLocation: [[1,2], [3,5], [4,1]]
                }

    ...

    //query
    SpecialSignsLocation = entity.persons_signs_location
                          .Where(c => c.PersonId == persons.Id)
                          .Select(s => new { s.Location, s.Sign})
                          .ToDictionary(l => l.Location, l => l.Sign)
```

I wrote a request, but I flies exception:

**Expression LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary**

There are 3 tables: Persons, PersonsSignsHair, PersonsSignsBodyType. One person may have a lot of special signs:

[image: Picture]

```
public List<object> GetPerson(int id)
{
   var query = (from persons in entity.persons where persons.Id.Equals(id)
               join signs_body_type in entity.persons_signs_body_type 
                 on persons.Id equals signs_body_type.PersonId into _signs_body_type
                      from signs_body_type in _signs_body_type.DefaultIfEmpty()

               join signs_hair in entity.persons_signs_hair 
                on persons.Id equals signs_hair.PersonId into _signs_hair
                      from signs_hair in _signs_hair.DefaultIfEmpty()

               select new Person
                      {
                          PersonName = persons.PersonName,
                          PersonLastName = persons.PersonLastName,
                          PersonPatronymic = persons.PersonPatronymic,
                          SpecialSigns = new PersonSpecialSigns()
                          {
                              BodyType = _signs_body_type.Select(c => c.PersonBodyType),
                              Hair = _signs_hair.Select(h => h.PersonHair)
                          }
                 });

     return query.ToList<object>();
}
```

After the query, the result is converted into JSON. The output, I would expect the following result:

```
[
    {
        SpecialSigns:  {
            BodyType:  [1, 2],
            Hair:  [3, 1, 2]
        },

        PersonName: "Aaa",
        PersonLastName: "Bbb",
        PersonPatronymic: "Ccc",

    },
]
```

Instead, the result is duplicated 6 times.

```
[
    {
        SpecialSigns:  {
            BodyType:  [1, 2],
            Hair:  [3, 1, 2]
        },

        PersonName: "Aaa",
        PersonLastName: "Bbb",
        PersonPatronymic: "Ccc",

    },
{
        SpecialSigns:  {
            BodyType:  [1, 2],
            Hair:  [3, 1, 2]
        },

        PersonName: "Aaa",
        PersonLastName: "Bbb",
        PersonPatronymic: "Ccc"

    },
{
        SpecialSigns:  {
            BodyType:  [1, 2],
            Hair:  [3, 1, 2]
        },

        PersonName: "Aaa",
        PersonLastName: "Bbb",
        PersonPatronymic: "Ccc"

    },
{
        SpecialSigns:  {
            BodyType:  [1, 2],
            Hair:  [3, 1, 2]
        },

        PersonName: "Aaa",
        PersonLastName: "Bbb",
        PersonPatronymic: "Ccc"

    },
{
        SpecialSigns:  {
            BodyType:  [1, 2],
            Hair:  [3, 1, 2]
        },

        PersonName: "Aaa",
        PersonLastName: "Bbb",
        PersonPatronymic: "Ccc"

    },
{
        SpecialSigns:  {
            BodyType:  [1, 2],
            Hair:  [3, 1, 2]
        },

        PersonName: "Aaa",
        PersonLastName: "Bbb",
        PersonPatronymic: "Ccc"

    }
]
```

**Question:** How do I combine the special identifiers, and will bring them to the array?

Comment: Please include the result that you get also.

Comment: @wdosanjos I think he was clear enough: *the result is duplicated 6 times*

Comment: If you only want one record you could do a `FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following.  The `join's` are causing a cartesian product.

```
public List<object> GetPerson(int id)
{
  var query = (from persons in entity.persons where persons.Id.Equals(id)

              select new Person
                     {
                         PersonName = persons.PersonName,
                         PersonLastName = persons.PersonLastName,
                         PersonPatronymic = persons.PersonPatronymic,
                         SpecialSigns = new PersonSpecialSigns()
                         {
                             BodyType = entity.persons_signs_body_type
                                              .Where(c => c.PersonId == persons.Id)
                                              .Select(c => c.PersonBodyType),
                             Hair = entity.persons_signs_hair
                                          .Where(c => c.PersonId == persons.Id)
                                          .Select(h => h.PersonHair)
                         }
                });

    return query.ToList<object>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a shot at this. But, I am almost sure that if you use `DefaultIfEmpty()`, you are bringing a [Left Outer Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) to your results. So, that is why you are probably duplicating everything. Omit this and you'll have your inner join (what I think you are looking for)

```
var query = from persons in entity.persons where persons.Id == id 
            select new Person
            {
                 PersonName = persons.PersonName,
                 PersonLastName = persons.PersonLastName,
                 PersonPatronymic = persons.PersonPatronymic,
                 SpecialSigns = new PersonSpecialSigns()
                 {
                    BodyType = entity.persons_signs_body_type
                                     .Where(i => i.PersonId == id) 
                                     .Select(i => i.PersonBodyType),
                    Hair = entity.persons_signs_hair
                                 .Where(i => i.PersonId == id)
                                 .Select(i => i.PersonHair)
                 }
            };
```

Also, as a recommendation I would use `FirstOrDefault()` to check if the person exists first and then I would populate the class.

```
var personData = entity.persons.FirstOrDefault(i = i.Id == id);

if(personData != null)
{
    var person = new Person
    {
        PersonName = personData.PersonName,
        PersonLastName = personData.PersonLastName,
        PersonPatronymic = personData.PersonPatronymic,
        SpecialSigns = new PersonSpecialSigns()
        {
            BodyType = entity.persons_signs_body_type
                             .Where(i => i.PersonId == personData.Id) 
                             .Select(i => i.PersonBodyType),
            Hair = entity.persons_signs_hair
                         .Where(i => i.PersonId == personData.Id)
                         .Select(i => i.PersonHair)
         }
   };
   //continue with the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short hand linq here should work fine.

```
public List<object> GetPerson(int id)
{
    var query = entity.persons.First(x=> x.Id == id).Select(x=> new Person
                {
                     PersonName = x.PersonName,
                     PersonLastName = x.PersonLastName,
                     PersonPatronymic = x.PersonPatronymic,
                     SpecialSigns = new PersonSpecialSigns                         
                     {
                         BodyType = entity.persons_signs_body_type
                                      .Where(y => y.PersonId == x.Id)
                                      .Select(y => y.PersonBodyType),
                         Hair = entity.persons_signs_hair
                                      .Where(y => y.PersonId == x.Id)
                                      .Select(y => y.PersonHair)
                     }
                 });

    return query.ToList<object>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework and your entities looks similar to these:

Person.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string PersonName { get; set; }
public string PersonLastName { get; set; }
public string PersonPatronymic { get; set; }

public ICollection<PersonsSignsHair> PersonsSignsHair { get; set; }
public ICollection<PersonsSignsBodyType> PersonsSignsBodyType { get; set; }
```

PersonsSignsHair.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int PersonId { get; set; }
public string PersonHair { get; set; }
```

PersonsSignsBodyType.cs

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int PersonId { get; set; }
public string PersonBodyType { get; set; }
```

And you have context like that:

```
public DbSet<PersonsSignsHair> PersonsSignsHair { get; set; }
public DbSet<PersonsSignsBodyType> PersonsSignsBodyType { get; set; }
public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

You can load Person with related entities like this

```
entity.People.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(y => y.PersonsSignsHair).Include(z => z.PersonsSignsBodyType).FirstOrDefault();
```